# Have child div stretch to remaining width of parent div who has variable width

Tags: css, html

I tried searching for this exact issue I'm having and I couldn't really find any solutions. So currently this is where I'm at:

```
<div style="min-width:800px; max-width:1280px;">
    <img style="width:300px; height:300px; display:block; float:left;"/>
    <div style="float:left;">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: diagram]

Currently the div with text in it just pops it right below the image, which is what it's supposed to do. I just don't know how to get how I want it. I've been trying to avoid table display...

Anyways, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should give the text div a width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
<div style="min-width:800px; max-width:1280px; position:relative;">
    <img style="width:300px; height:300px; display:block; float:left; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"/>
    <div style="margin-left:300px;">
        <!-- Now this content will grow as much as it can without disturbing the column of the image -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, that make sense and is intuitive. I still feel like there is a cleaner solution but it'll work for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Positioning!

```
<div style="min-width:800px; max-width:1280px; position: relative; padding-left: 305px;">
    <img style="width:300px; height:300px; display:block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;"/>
    <div style="background: white;">

    </div>
</div>
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsRVc/

---

#### Longer Text Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsRVc/1/

Comment: Is it possible only using floats? I have other content in the parent div that I don't want pushed over by the padding.

Comment: Just using the floats, it gets down. But this works across all the browsers. There is no padding given.

Comment: What do you mean it gets down?

Comment: Gets down in the sense, the text moves left, when the image is small.

Comment: Yeah but I want to avoid that

Comment: No I don't get you. Avoid what?